# Show Div on Dynamically Created RadioButton Selection (PHP-AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, radiobuttonlist

I have created radio button is created on client side and when I click it, it should show my existing div i.e. ifPrint

Please have a look at code I am trying:

radio button creation:

```
var optiondiv = document.getElementById('option-div');

document.getElementById('create').onclick = function () {

newopt = document.getElementById('new-option').value;
if(newopt){
    var input = document.createElement('input'),
    label = document.createElement('label');
    input.type = "radio";
    input.setAttribute("value", newopt);
    input.setAttribute("checked", true);
    input.setAttribute("name", "radio-name");
    label.appendChild(input);
    label.innerHTML += newopt+'<br>'; 
    optiondiv.appendChild(label);
    document.getElementById('new-option').value = '';

    $.post(
        "equipments1.php", 
        { 
            "newopt": newopt  
        }, 
        function(data) {
            if(data.success){
                alert('Successful Added To dB');
                document.getElementById('newopt').checked = false;

            //  if (document.getElementById('newopt').checked) {
//document.getElementById('ifPrint').style.display = 'block';
        //$(#ifPrint).show();
                //$(#ifPrint).show();
            }else{
                alert('Not Add To DB');

            }

    });

}else{
    alert('Please Enter Radio Button Value.');
    return false;
}



};
```

New function for showing Div ifPrint:

```
$('input[type=radio][name=newopt]').change(function() {
$(#ifPrint).show();

});
```

Please guide if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use click instead of change, and also you missing quotes in your code, and it's better to use "on" than "click" function if element is created after dinamicaly

```
$('body').on('click','input[type=radio][name=newopt]',function () {
    $('#ifPrint').show();
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RhnvU/5846/ I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, is this fiddle ok, if not explain please what need to happen. Or you want to show div if newly created radio is clicked?

Comment: Yes. I want to show my div ifPrint on new radiobutton click i.e. newopt. Pls see in fiddle below. Pls click at: 

jsfiddle.net/engr1111/RhnvU/5842
 
and see newopt is created new radio button and i am showing my div in the end

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RhnvU/5849/ new created radio name is "radio-name", not "newopt" , it will detect click now

Comment: but how will it work on page load. when I load page, it does not show

Comment: It was hard for me to understand what is your goal. Glad that you have done it finally :)

Comment: thanks a lot. Just tell its checked always. I mean on selecting other radio, it should uncheck. Wont it work?

if (document.getElementById('radio-name').checked) {
  //if (document.getElementById('newopt').checked) {
   //   $(#ifPrint).show();
        document.getElementById('ifPc').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('buttons').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('ifPrint').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('ifScan').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('ifPhone').style.display = 'none';
        
         
 }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124870/discussion-between-ban17-and-mazhar-iqbal-rana).